# c# how can I represent a singal I'm getting in dBm as a 5 bars display?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, display

I have a C# windows form that shows the signal I'm reading from my device.

the data is in dBm and can be -110-->-51 dBm.

how can I show it as signal strenght display (like we all have on phones)
for example :

```
-110-95 1

 -94-84 2

 -83-72 3

 -71-60 4

 -59-51 5
```

any good and easy idea? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to use a PictureBox and to have a different image for each of the signal strenght (i'm pretty sure this is how it's done on phones)

```
    private void SetSignalStrenghtDisplay(int strenght)
    {
        if(strenght < -110)
            pictureBox1.Image = //0%image
        else if(strenght <= -95)
            pictureBox1.Image = //20%image
        // and so on...
    }
```

If you don't want to deal with images, you can always try to do your own UserControl, but it would require a lot more work.

Comment: so I need to create 5 images ?  I never used Image function before. can you show me howto? lets say all the images are : image1(for 20%) . image2(for 40%) etc..   Thanks ,